# Hiiden expression for tablix refers to the field 'claimid'

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am working on ssrs report but i have an error

"the Hidden expression for the tablix ‘Tablix9’ refers to the field ‘ClaimID’.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope."

But i dont have any hidden expressions for the tablix

i looked in Tablix visibility properties group properties.But i couldnt find any.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 9):

You have definitely got a Hidden expression defined somewhere for Tablix9. Please check the following locations:

[image: Tablix Properties]

If "Show or hide based on an expression" is checked, click on the "fx" button to see this Hidden expression.

[image: Tablix Properties Grid]

If Tablix9 is selected from the Property Grid drop-down menu, check Hidden property under "Visibility" group for the Hidden expression.

If you are still unable to find it, open the report XML code by clicking View -> Code in the menu, press CTRL + F and look for `<Hidden>`. If found, you will see the `Hidden` expression defined in a `Visibility` tag, similar to this:

```
  <Tablix Name="Tablix1">
    ...
    <Visibility>
      <Hidden>=Iif(IsNothing(Fields!ClaimID.Value), True, False)</Hidden>
    </Visibility>
  </Tablix>
```

Looking at the XML tag it is contained in should tell you where it is defined. In the example above, it is in my Tablix: "Tablix1".

Use this method to trace where your Hidden expression is defined. You can also delete it from the XML code too.

Comment: Got the same problem and found the unseen hidden tag by xml search!